Google OAuth2 invalid_client on server, works on local
I am building a web application with go and using goth to handle authentication with Google OAuth2. I have a working implementation running locally in docker container, but the same setup does not work on the server. The error message I get is "401: invalid_client" and only "flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow" as extra information.
The client_id and client_secret are from env variables and I have confirmed that they are correctly set on the container. The exact same container setup is running correctly on my local machine. I can also see from the request that the client_id and redirect_url are correctly set.
The only differences are:

server is running nginx as reverse proxy and for https
server is rhel, instead of windows like my local machine. The docker containers are both the same though

I can access the site normally but cannot get through the authentication.
The application is running on the port 8008.
What I have tried:

Solutions in invalid_client in google oauth2
Checking the client_id and client_secret a million times
Recreating the Google credentials
Recreating the whole Google project
Set the name and email of the product
Trying multiple different urls for authorized JavaScript origins, with both port 8008 specified and not specified
Waiting for days for the changes to take effect.

Nothing works. Any idea on how to fix this? My best guess is that nginx is causing some issues.
Nginx config:
server {

  server_name sub.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8008/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
  if ($host = sub.example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  server_name sub.example.com;
  listen 80;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}


Considering there's only a description of your problem; but no concrete code and/or nginx configuration, your guess is probably better than what others might say.

This question is similar to: invalid_client in google oauth2. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have gone through this post (multiple times). I added editing the product name and email to the list of things I have tried though.

The thing is, without including your code and/or nginx reverse proxy configuration, it's really difficult to figure out what could be the issue.  If you feel it's nginx, perhaps check the nginx log?

Nginx log does not really give me any info. I added the nginx config now
